# Как передать данные из модального окна?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Всем привет.

1. Есть род компонент.(Schedule)
2. В род компоненте => Есть выпадающий список с инфой о сотруднике.(TableItemTittle)

```html
<TableItemTitle
                    tableFioPermission={tableFioPermission}
                    cellEmployee={cellEmployee}
                    tableEventTypePermission={tableEventTypePermission}
                    cell={cell}
                    cellEventTypeUnsaved={cellEventTypeUnsaved}
                    tableDatePermission={tableDatePermission}
                    tableTimeStartPermission={tableTimeStartPermission}
                    timeStartCell={timeStartCell}
                    timeEndCell={timeEndCell}
                    tableTimeEndPermission={tableTimeEndPermission}
                    tableActionsPermission={tableActionsPermission}
                    checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon={checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon}
                    deleteShiftCell={deleteShiftCell}
                    dateStartedButNotFinished={dateStartedButNotFinished}
                    setChangeEditActivityModalShow={setChangeEditActivityModalShow}
                    setActivityModalData={setActivityModalData}
                    deleteActivityCell={deleteActivityCell}
                  />
```

3. Есть модалка(EditActivityModal). Есть деятельность у сотрудника, нажимаю на кнопку изменить и она вылазит.
   Хочу поменять в этой модалке деятельность, но она не меняется. При том что есть функционал на смену даты и он работает.

В Род.компоненте создал состояние и hanlde.

```
 const [changeActivDateName, setChangeActivDateName] = useState<any>(null)


  const handleUpdateDateName = (value) => {
setChangeActivDateName(value)
```

}

И передал это дело в

```
         <EditActivityModal
          setNeedToUpdate={() => setNeedToUpdateData(true)}
          setChangeEditActivityModalShow={setChangeEditActivityModalShow}
          funcUnitFilterField={funcUnitFilterField}
          filteredEmployees={filteredEmployees}
          funcUnitsDict={funcUnitsDict}
          activitiesDict={activitiesDict}
          prepareCellForEdit={prepareCellForEdit}
          activityData={activityModalData}
          onActivityDateChange={handleUpdateDateName}
         />
```

В EditActivityModal принял это дело

```
export interface AddActivityModalProps {
  onActivityDateChange(value): void
```

}

Есть функция, которая должна обрабатывать это **postAddActivity**, но она не ловит это.
Написал функцию activityGood, которая как раз отслеживает изменение на деятельность, но ее применение ничем не помогло, значение name(деятельности) не передается в TableItemTitle.

```html
export interface AddActivityModalProps {
  setNeedToUpdate(): void
  setChangeEditActivityModalShow(arg1: boolean): void,
  funcUnitFilterField: string,
  filteredEmployees: string[],
  funcUnitsDict: FuncUnitsDictionary[],
  activitiesDict: ActivitiesDictionary[],
  activityData: ActivityModalData,
  prepareCellForEdit(employeeId: string, activityObjectId: string, activityId: string, startDateTime: string, endDateTIme: string): void
  onActivityDateChange(value): void
}

const EditActivityModal: FC<AddActivityModalProps> = ({prepareCellForEdit, activityData, setChangeEditActivityModalShow, activitiesDict, funcUnitsDict,onActivityDateChange}) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date(activityData.date))
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<Date>(null)
  const [timeStart, setTimeStart] = useState<string>(activityData.startTime)
  const [timeEnd, setTimeEnd] = useState<string>(activityData.endTime)

  const [funcUnit, setFuncUnit] = useState()
  const [selectedEmployees, setSelectedEmployees] = useState([])
  const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState<string>(activityData.activityId)

  const postAddActivity = () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const [timeStartHours, timeStartMinutes] = [timeStart.split(':')[0], timeStart.split(':')[1]]
    // @ts-ignore
    const [timeEndHors, timeEndMinutes] = [timeEnd.split(':')[0], timeEnd.split(':')[1]]

    const startDateTime = new Date(new Date(startDate.setHours(parseInt(String(timeStartHours)))).setMinutes(parseInt(timeStartMinutes))).toISOString()
    const endDateTime = new Date(new Date(startDate.setHours(parseInt(String(timeEndHors)))).setMinutes(parseInt(timeEndMinutes))).toISOString()


    const activityGood = activitiesDict.find((activ) => {
      if (activ.id === selectedActivity) {
        return activ.name
      }
    })
    console.log(activityGood)

    if (activityGood) {
      prepareCellForEdit(
        activityData.employee.objectId,
        activityData.employeeObjectIdConnect,
        selectedActivity,
        startDateTime,
        endDateTime
      )
      onActivityDateChange(activityGood.name)
      // prepareCellForEdit(activityData.employee.objectId, activityData.employeeObjectIdConnect, activityData.activityId, startDateTime, endDateTime)

      setChangeEditActivityModalShow(false)
    }

  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      }}
    >

      <main style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}>

        <TextWithGreenBackground value={'Деятельность'} />


        <Select
          value={selectedActivity}
          label={'Корректировка'}
          style={{ width: 260, padding: '10px 10px' }}
          // onChange={((index, value) => {
          //   setSelectedActivity(value)
          // })}
          onChange={(_, value) => {
            const activityGood = activitiesDict.find((activity) => activity.id === value);
            if (activityGood) {
              setSelectedActivity(activityGood.id);
              onActivityDateChange(activityGood.name)
            }
          }}
        >
          {activitiesDict.map((activity, i) => (
            <OptionItem key={i} value={activity.id}>
              {activity.name}
            </OptionItem>
          ))
          }
        </Select>

        <div style={{ marginLeft: 10, display: 'flex', gap: 5, marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 40 }}>
          <DateInput style={{ width: 180 }} value={startDate || new Date(activityData.date)} onChange={setStartDate}
                     label={'Дата'} />
          <TimeInput
            // disabled={activityData.activityStarted}
            style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
            label={'Время работы'}
            value={timeStart}
            onChange={(value => {
              setTimeStart(value);
            })} />
          <span style={{ marginTop: 23, fontWeight: 500, fontSize: 20 }}>-</span>
          <TimeInput
            value={timeEnd}
            error={timeEnd < timeStart ? ErrorType.ERROR : undefined}
            errorMessage={timeEnd < timeStart && 'Время окончания не может быть раньше времени начала'}
            onChange={(value => setTimeEnd(value))}
            style={{ marginTop: 19 }} />
          <Switch disabled checked={false} label={'Повторяющаяся деятельность'}
                  style={{ marginTop: 23, marginLeft: 10 }} />
        </div>

        <TextWithGreenBackground value={'Условия повторения деятельности'} />

        <div style={{ marginLeft: 10, display: 'flex', gap: 20 }}>
          <DateInput style={{ width: 180, marginTop: 35 }} value={endDate} disabled onChange={setEndDate}
                     label={'Дата окончания'} />
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <p style={{ fontSize: 14, color: '#757575', fontWeight: 400, marginLeft: 5, margin: '10px 0 0 0' }}>Дни
              недели</p>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                ПН
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                ВТ
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                СР
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32, whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
              >
                ЧТ
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                ПТ
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                СБ
              </Button>
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{ borderRadius: 100, padding: '7px 12px', margin: '7px 5px', height: 32 }}
              >
                ВС
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <div
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          borderTop: '1px solid rgb(131 127 127 / 22%)',
          paddingTop: '20px',
          gap: '5px',
        }}
      >
        <CancelButton
          id='3d2a279f-c49c-46c1-aa38-a309a679310e'
          onClick={() => setChangeEditActivityModalShow(false)}
        >
          Отмена
        </CancelButton>
        <AcceptButton
          id='274276ff-b377-4085-bc6e-0ab387728e03'
          disabled={timeEnd < timeStart}
          onClick={() => postAddActivity()}
        >
          Выполнить
        </AcceptButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditActivityModal;
```

**Так же вот код TableItemTitle**

```html
interface ITableItemTitle {
  tableFioPermission: any,
  cellEmployee: EmployeeInfoItem,
  tableEventTypePermission: any,
  cell: CellsData,
  cellEventTypeUnsaved: string,
  tableDatePermission: any,
  tableTimeStartPermission: any,
  timeStartCell: string,
  timeEndCell: string,
  tableTimeEndPermission: any,
  tableActionsPermission: any,
  checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon: boolean,
  deleteShiftCell: (shiftObjectId: string, unsavedCellId: number) => void,
  dateStartedButNotFinished: boolean,
  setChangeEditActivityModalShow: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
  setActivityModalData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ActivityModalData>>,
  deleteActivityCell: (activityObjectId: string, unsavedCellId: number) => void
}

const TableItemTitle: FC<ITableItemTitle> = ({
  tableFioPermission,
  cellEmployee,
  tableEventTypePermission,
  cell,
  cellEventTypeUnsaved,
  tableDatePermission,
  tableTimeStartPermission,
  timeStartCell,
  timeEndCell,
  tableTimeEndPermission,
  tableActionsPermission,
  checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon,
  deleteShiftCell,
  dateStartedButNotFinished,
  setChangeEditActivityModalShow,
  setActivityModalData,
  deleteActivityCell
}) => {

  const [activityGoodData, setActivityGoodData] = useState(null)
  const handleActivityDataUpdate = (data) => {
    setActivityGoodData(data)
  }

  const cellInfo = cell.cellInfo;

  const isShowShiftIcon = ((cellInfo.unsaved || cellInfo.haveError)
    || (cellInfo.type === RowTypes.Shift && checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon));

  const isShowActivityEditIcon = cellInfo.type === RowTypes.Activity && !cellInfo.unsaved
    && (dateStartedButNotFinished || checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon);

  const isShowActivityTrashIcon = ((cellInfo.unsaved || cellInfo.haveError)
    || (cellInfo.type === RowTypes.Activity && checkAbilityToShowDeleteIcon));

  const getColor = (cellInfo: CellInfo) => {
    if (cellInfo.unsaved) {
      return 'rgb(164 205 255 / 50%)';
    } else {
      return 'rgb(229 229 229 / 50%)';
    }
  }

  // Название начала и конца смены / сокращенной смены
  const cellEventTypeSaved = cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
    ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002')
    ? `Смена с сокращением (${getShortShiftName(cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002'))})`
    :`Смена (${getShiftName(cell.cellInfo)})`;

  const regexp = /[-,.,\s,:]/;
  const shiftShortDateStartUTC = calculateDate(cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002')?.timeStart);
  const [sY, sM, sD, shortHours, shortMinutes] = formatDate(shiftShortDateStartUTC)?.split(regexp);
  const shiftShortDateStartFormatted = `${shortHours}:${shortMinutes}`;

  const savedEventType = cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002')
    ? `Смена с сокращением (${cellInfo.timeStart}-${shiftShortDateStartFormatted})` : cellInfo.eventType;


  return (
    <div
      style={{
        fontSize: 14,
        backgroundColor: getColor(cellInfo),
        marginBottom: 3,
        display: 'flex',
      }}
    >

      {tableFioPermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 429px' }}>{cutString(cellEmployee.fullName, 50)}</Td>
      )}

      {tableEventTypePermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 429px' }}>
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && ((cellInfo.unsaved && cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
            ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.id === 'AC002')) || cellInfo.unsaved || cellInfo.haveError)
            ? cellEventTypeUnsaved : savedEventType
            // cellInfo.eventType
          }
        </Td>
      )}

      {tableDatePermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 429px' }}>{cellInfo.date}</Td>
      )}

      {tableTimeStartPermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 169px' }}>
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && (cellInfo.unsaved || cellInfo.haveError) ? timeStartCell : cellInfo.timeStart}
        </Td>
      )}

      {tableTimeEndPermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 186px' }}>

          {/* Смена с сокращением и сохранена - ОК */}
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && !cellInfo.unsaved && !cellInfo.haveError && cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
            ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002') && shiftShortDateStartFormatted}

          {/* Смена с сокращением и не сохранена - ОК */}
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && cellInfo.unsaved && !cellInfo.haveError && cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
            ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002') && timeEndCell}

          {/* Смена без сокращения и сохранена - ОК */}
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && !cellInfo.unsaved && !cellInfo.haveError && !cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
            ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002') && cellInfo.timeEnd}

          {/* Смена без сокращения и не сохранена - ОК */}
          {cellInfo.type === 'SHIFT' && cellInfo.unsaved && !cellInfo.haveError && !cell.scheduleInfo.relatedActivities
            ?.find(shortShift => shortShift.relatedActivityId === 'AC002') && timeEndCell}

          {/* КОРРЕКТИРОВКА или HR событие без сокращения и не сохранена - ОК */}
          {cellInfo.type !== 'SHIFT' && cellInfo.timeEnd}
        </Td>
      )}

      {tableActionsPermission?.visible && (
        <Td style={{ border: 'none', flex: '0 1 150px' }}>
          <div onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()} style={{position: 'relative'}}>

            {isShowShiftIcon && (
              <Icon
                type={IconType.TRASH}
                style={{
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 25
                }}
                onClick={() => deleteShiftCell(cell.scheduleInfo.employeeShiftObjectId, cellInfo.unsavedId)}
              />
            )}

            {isShowActivityEditIcon && (
              <>
                {
                  <Icon
                    type={IconType.EDIT}
                    style={{
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      position: 'absolute',
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0
                    }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setChangeEditActivityModalShow(true);
                      setActivityModalData({
                        employee: cellEmployee,
                        employeeObjectIdConnect: cell.scheduleInfo.activityObjectId,
                        eventType: cellInfo.eventType,
                        startTime: cellInfo?.timeStart,
                        endTime: cellInfo?.timeEnd,
                        date: cellInfo.date,
                        activityId: cellInfo.activityId,
                        activityStarted: dateStartedButNotFinished
                      })
                      }}
                  />
                }

                {isShowActivityTrashIcon && (
                  <Icon
                    type={IconType.TRASH}
                    style={{
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                      position: 'absolute',
                      top: 0,
                      left: 25
                    }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteActivityCell(cell.scheduleInfo.activityObjectId, cellInfo.unsavedId);
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </Td>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableItemTitle;
```

В общем возникает вопрос Как передать данные из модального окна в TableItemTitle, который выпадает из родительского компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Такие вещи достаточно просто дебажатся. В родительском ком-те сделай

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('changeActivDateName', changeActivDateName)
}, [changeActivDateName]);
```

что бы убедиться, что из EditActivityModal действительно хендлится handleUpdateDateName
Вопрос в том, что я не вижу связи changeActivDateName и компонета списка TableItemTittle. TableItemTittle перерендерится, если в его пропсах пришли новые данные, т.е. эти данные должны зависеть от changeActivDateName. Если в коде (который мы не видим -  Schedule) есть что-то типа

```
const {tableFioPermission, cellEmployee //и т.д} = changeActivDateName;
```

то обновления TableItemTittle должны работать

Comment: А как правильно тогда передать связь changeActivDateName и компонета TableItemTittle?

Comment: Сделать единый источник данных для родителя и чилдренов. Например это будет некий объект аctivDate

Comment: В EditActivityModal  сделал изменения, они в родителе изменили activData , тот в свою очередь перерендерил TableItemTittle